# Jenkins slave creation for Windows server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am trying to use Jenkins for deployment of my patch so here the server on which I want to deploy is a Windows server and my Jenkins is a AIX system and also my Jenkins version is 2.9 and it's run on java 7 where as the application I am deploying has a constraint that it could only be run on java 6 which is on Windows hence I need a solution for this java 7 to to java 6 slave connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by just installing a java 7 on the windows server with the constraint,
but the java 7 isn't configured in the path variable i have kept a command handy with the complete path of bin directory of the java 7 installed on the windows so i can connect via slave.jar to my jenkins server giving the path and executing the slave.jar with java 7 so that i dont get a major minor version error, and later on since its not in the path further use java 6 for later processing of windows server.